# Google Android kotlin Codelab; can I use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to replace all `PhotoGridAdapter.MarsPropertyViewHolder`?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

### I compared the two Google Codelabs,find some problem in how to normalize `Android RecyclerView Codes`.

### github link as following:

1. [First CodeLab use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` as type](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/3ae0d7290be7a23a9914254c43b2840f89c37ca0/RecyclerViewHeaders/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt#L38)
2. [Second CodeLab use `PhotoGridAdapter.MarsPropertyViewHolder` as type](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/3ae0d7290be7a23a9914254c43b2840f89c37ca0/MarsRealEstateFinal/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/marsrealestate/overview/PhotoGridAdapter.kt#L34)
3. My changed Second CodeLab as following:

```kotlin
package com.example.android.marsrealestate.overview

//import android.widget.ListAdapter
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.android.marsrealestate.databinding.GridViewItemBinding
import com.example.android.marsrealestate.network.MarsProperty

class PhotoGridAdapter : ListAdapter<MarsProperty,
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MarsPropertyViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val marsProperty = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(marsProperty) //FIXME:<<<------will cause error
    }

    class MarsPropertyViewHolder(private var binding:
                                 GridViewItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(marsProperty: MarsProperty) {
            binding.property = marsProperty
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): MarsPropertyViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = GridViewItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                return MarsPropertyViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MarsProperty>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MarsProperty, newItem: MarsProperty): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MarsProperty, newItem: MarsProperty): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

### questions:

I try to replace all second code from `PhotoGridAdapter.MarsPropertyViewHolder`(Customize ViewHolder) to  `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`,but will cause error.

error as following:
`PhotoGridAdapter > onBindViewHolder > holder.bind` not found.

why,First Codelab work but second Codelab not work?

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView.ViewHolder` doesn't have `bind` method, it is present only in your custom `MarsPropertyViewHolder`. if you still want to declare common `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, but want to use extended `MarsPropertyViewHolder` then you have to cast holder as below:

```
(holder as MarsPropertyViewHolder).bind(marsProperty)
```

be shure that `onCreateViewHolder` will always return `MarsPropertyViewHolder`, if not then you may get `ClassCastException` in `onBindViewHolder`. optionally you may use some check: `if(holder is MarsPropertyViewHolder) {...}`

Comment: thanks for  your answer. The First CodeLab can work maybe use `kotlin smart cast`,I saw Android Studio hint.